# Internet keeps disconnecting Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, internet, disconnect

On my laptop my Wifi keeps disconnecting. Every time I re-connect it works for a few seconds but after that it drops.

I've looked at many related questions but none of the answers seems to work for me.

**$ lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2**

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1091] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1043:14c7]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx
```

**$ lshw -c network**

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: 24:0a:64:2b:be:83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-59-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.2.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:f7d00000-f7d7ffff memory:f7d80000-f7d8ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 10
       serial: ac:22:0b:6b:ec:86
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:29 memory:f7c00000-f7c3ffff ioport:e000(size=128)
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

**$ dmesg|tail**

```
[  638.957018] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[  638.957019] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[  638.957021] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  638.957022] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[  639.937787] wlp2s0: authenticate with a0:ec:80:47:05:8c
[  639.960416] wlp2s0: send auth to a0:ec:80:47:05:8c (try 1/3)
[  639.962881] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  639.965111] wlp2s0: associate with a0:ec:80:47:05:8c (try 1/3)
[  639.968755] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from a0:ec:80:47:05:8c (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[  639.968862] wlp2s0: associated
```

**$ lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b354 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd UVC 1.00 device HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```